# SVG showing extra piece when array have more then 8 items

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

I am creating SVG Donuts in my Angular application everything is working fine but When i have 8+ items in my Array its showing extra Piece in my Donut.  I have used `| slice:0:8` pipe but no Luck.
if i remove non `ngFor` circle from svg it shows blank space.

```
<svg width="100%" height="260px" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
   <text x="50%" y="53%" style="font-size: 6px; font-weight: bold;" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" [attr.fill]="compare.color">10%</text>
   <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#f3f3f3" stroke-width="7"></circle>
   <circle *ngFor="let circle of compare_array | slice:0:8;" attr.class="donut-segment{{ i }}" [attr.data-per]="circle.rev_percentage" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" [attr.stroke]="circle.color" stroke-width="7" stroke-dasharray="40 60" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
</svg>
```

Expectation:

[image: This is Expectation]

Current Result:

[image: This is Result]

Comment: Are you sure that the percent of all circles sum to 100? Without looking at the array that hold your circles, it is hard to understand what is going on. Create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so we can better understand your code.

Comment: Exactly, its Not 100% because i have more item which have remaining % . That's why extra space is coming up. Now How can i make it 100?

Comment: You need to normalize the percentage values so that their sum is exactly 100. Check out this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fehidemexu/edit?html,js,console).